# Altium 17 polygon not pouring over same net

Tags: altium

[image]

I am not able to make the polygon pour over traces of the same net. As you can see from the picture, the GND traces are not connected to the GND plane. Can you tell me how to enable this operation? I am using altium17.

Comment: In the settings of the polygon pour have you set the pour to "pour over all same net" or words to that kind of thing? (I'm sorry, I can't remeber what words they used in Altium 17)

Comment: Yes you are correct. I founf the "pour over all same net objects"setting in the properties panel

Answer (score 1):

Given how the polygon is being spaced a given distance from the track, but *not* the pad, this looks like you may have a clearance Design Rule that's affecting it. In particular, there's a setting for such design rules that determines whether different nets or same nets are affected:

[image: Clearance Design Rule settings]

Make sure you have a rule that is set to *different* nets, otherwise it will create gaps between two objects (track and poly) belonging to the same net.

If you have more than one clearance rule, you'll need to verify their priority and scope are appropriate for your board.